# Input Styled text and image in EditText and save it as Html into database and fetch it in Textview or WebView Other Activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to input styled text and images into editText and save in into room database. I have already saved it as Html. All is working fine but the image not showing. I want to show it in text view both image and styled text. Output attach there, please see this below.
Where is the problem?

[My code output Loom like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iirKt.png)

[When input text and photo into editText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ric1.png)

I am using text-editor library
implementation 'com.github.chinalwb:are:0.1.7'

```
        // fetch data from database
    viewModel.getListLiveData().observe(this, new Observer<List<ModelClass>>() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<ModelClass> modelClasses) {

            titleShow.setText(modelClasses.get(position).getTitle());
            try {
                areTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(modelClasses.get(position).getContent()));
            } catch (Exception e) {
               areTextView.setText(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}

public static android.text.Html.ImageGetter imageGetter = new android.text.Html.ImageGetter() {
    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        Drawable drawable = null;
        drawable = Drawable.createFromPath(source);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable
                .getIntrinsicHeight());
        return drawable;
    }
};




    //save button click to send data ShowActivity
    findViewById(R.id.done).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //get data from input filed
            String titleTxt = title.getText().toString();
            //String contentTxt = Html.toHtml(mEditText.getText());
            String content = mEditText.getHtml();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra(TITLE, titleTxt);
            intent.putExtra(CONTENT, content);
            intent.putExtra(DATE, date);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Get image from gallery and upload into editText:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mToolbar.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```